# Error with Entity Bundle Classes

Tags: 9

I created a bundle class that extends the taxonomy term class, but I get this error.

> Error: Interface 'Drupal\my_artists\Entity\ArtistTermInterface' not found in include() (line 15 of /xxx/drupal/web/modules/private/my_artists/src/Entity/ArtistTerm.php)

I set the bundle class in the *my_artists.module* file.

```php
use Drupal\my_artists\Entity\ArtistTerm;

function my_artists_entity_bundle_info_alter(array &$bundles): void {
  $bundles['taxonomy_term']['artist']['class'] = ArtistTerm::class;
}
```

In /src/ArtistTermInterface.php I defined the bundle class interface.

```php
namespace Drupal\my_artists\Entity;
    
use Drupal\taxonomy\TermInterface;
    
/**
  * Represents a ArtistTerm entity.
  */
interface ArtistTermInterface extends TermInterface {}
```

In /src/Entity/ArtistTerm.php, I defined the bundle class.

```php
namespace Drupal\my_artists\Entity;
    
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageInterface;
use Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Term;
    
/**
 * Defines the ArtistTerm class.
 */
class ArtistTerm extends Term implements ArtistTermInterface {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function preSave(EntityStorageInterface $storage) {
    $this->set('field_some_field', 'some value');
    parent::preSave($storage);
  }

}
```

Why do I get the error?

Comment: Did you put `use Drupal\my_artists\Entity\Artist;` on the top of the file containing `my_artists_entity_bundle_info_alter()`?

Comment: Either is that, or there is a typo in the code or the filenames. I take the module is installed, but there could be another module that is referring the `Artist` class.

Answer (score 1):

Entity bundle classes go in `/mymodule/src/Entity/Bundle/MyClass.php`.

To easily generate the bundle class and see what may be wrong, try the drush command `drush generate entity:bundle-class` and follow the prompts.

[Drush docs](https://www.drush.org/latest/generators/entity_bundle-class/)

Comment: No, that isn't required. The examples given in [Introducing bundle classes](https://www.drupal.org/node/3191609) use bundle classes like `Drupal\mymodule\Entity\BasicPage`.